# Optimización de consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, revisión-de-código

Tengo un pequeño problema con la optimización o diseño de cierta consulta en mysql, o por lo menos que a mi me choca bastante. Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
    IDmodalidad,IDtipocurso,IDarea,IDcurso,tagbloque,contenido
FROM bloques 
WHERE 
    (IDmodalidad = 1 AND IDtipocurso = 1 AND IDarea =1 AND IDcurso =1) OR
    (IDmodalidad = 1 AND IDtipocurso = 1 AND IDarea =1 AND IDcurso IS NULL) OR
    (IDmodalidad = 1 AND IDtipocurso = 1 AND IDarea IS NULL AND IDcurso =1) OR
    (IDmodalidad = 1 AND IDtipocurso IS NULL AND IDarea = 1 AND IDcurso = 1) OR 
    (IDmodalidad IS NULL AND IDtipocurso = 1 AND IDarea = 1 AND IDcurso = 1) OR 
    (IDmodalidad = 1 AND IDtipocurso = 1 AND IDarea IS NULL AND IDcurso IS NULL) OR
    (IDmodalidad = 1 AND IDtipocurso IS NULL AND IDarea = 1 AND IDcurso IS NULL) OR
    (IDmodalidad = 1 AND IDtipocurso IS NULL AND IDarea IS NULL AND IDcurso = 1) OR
    (IDmodalidad IS NULL AND IDtipocurso = 1 AND IDarea = 1 AND IDcurso IS NULL) OR 
    (IDmodalidad IS NULL AND IDtipocurso = 1 AND IDarea IS NULL AND IDcurso = 1) OR
    (IDmodalidad IS NULL AND IDtipocurso IS NULL AND IDarea = 1 AND IDcurso = 1) OR 
    (IDmodalidad = 1 AND IDtipocurso IS NULL AND IDarea IS NULL AND IDcurso IS NULL) OR
    (IDmodalidad IS NULL AND IDtipocurso =1 AND IDarea IS NULL AND IDcurso IS NULL) OR
    (IDmodalidad IS NULL AND IDtipocurso IS NULL AND IDarea = 1 AND IDcurso IS NULL) OR
    (IDmodalidad IS NULL AND IDtipocurso IS NULL AND IDarea IS NULL AND IDcurso =1)
```

Como se puede ver es un a sentencia creo que con demasiados OR por que lo que hago es buscar en la tabla  o que sea null o que sea un valor expecifico que he puesto 1 pero hay muchos valores.
La cuestión es si hay alguna manera de reducir esos OR's, o tiene que ser así.

Comment: Iba a sugerir que utilizases un diagrama de Karnaugh, pero antes una pregunta: te valen todas las combinaciones de los 4 campos excepto en la que todos son NULL, ¿correcto?

Answer (score 2):

No está mal esa consulta que tienes. Parece incluso que está así apropósito. Ten cuidado con cambiar las cosas porque sí.

Si la vez bien, parece una tabla de configuración. Eso es una ventaja. Los demás programadores entenderán inmediatamente de qué se trata.

Una alternativa es que interpretes eso como una pregunta de pertenencia en esa tabla de configuración: ¿Está este registro en la tabla de configuración?.

En ese caso, harías algo como:

```
SELECT
    IDmodalidad,IDtipocurso,IDarea,IDcurso,tagbloque,contenido
FROM bloques 
WHERE
    (IDmodalidad, IDtipocurso, IDarea, IDcurso) IN
    (
        (1,    1,    1,    1   ),
        (1,    1,    1,    NULL),
        (1,    1,    NULL, 1   ),
        (1,    NULL, 1,    1   ),
        (NULL, 1,    1,    1   ),
        (1,    1,    NULL, NULL),
        (1,    NULL, 1,    NULL),
        (1,    NULL, NULL, 1   ),
        (NULL, 1,    1,    NULL),
        (NULL, 1,    NULL, 1   ),
        (NULL, NULL, 1,    1   ),
        (1,    NULL, NULL, NULL),
        (NULL, 1,    NULL, NULL),
        (NULL, NULL, 1,    NULL),
        (NULL, NULL, NULL, 1   )
    )
```

Ahora, esto no tiene mucha diferencia con tu solución. Yo no la cambiaría. La coloqué para que te hagas una idea de la posibilidad, y por lo siguiente: si estás dispuesto a hacer una consulta adicional, para ganar flexibilidad, entonces mantén esa configuración en una tabla adicional (o en algún otro sitio como un archivo de configuración). Si la mantienes en una tabla adicional, la consulta quedaría como:

```
SELECT
    IDmodalidad,IDtipocurso,IDarea,IDcurso,tagbloque,contenido
FROM bloques 
WHERE
    (IDmodalidad, IDtipocurso, IDarea, IDcurso) IN SELECT * FROM bloques_conf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IDmodalidad, IDtipocurso, IDarea, IDcurso, tagbloque, contenido
FROM bloques 
WHERE (IDmodalidad IS NOT NULL OR 
       IDtipocurso IS NOT NULL OR
       IDarea IS NOT  NULL OR
       IDcurso IS NOT NULL) AND
      (IDmodalidad IS NULL OR IDmodalidad = 1) AND
      (IDtipocurso IS NULL OR IDtipocurso = 1) AND
      (IDarea IS NULL OR IDarea = 1) AND
      (IDcurso IS NULL OR IDcurso = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Viendo la consulta, parece que te valen todas las combinaciones de los 4 campos excepto en la que todos son NULL, así que podrías reducir de esta manera:

```
SELECT
    IDmodalidad,IDtipocurso,IDarea,IDcurso,tagbloque,contenido
FROM bloques 
WHERE 
    (IDmodalidad = 1 OR IDmodalidad IS NULL) AND
    (IDtipocurso = 1 OR IDtipocurso IS NULL) AND
    (IDarea      = 1 OR IDarea      IS NULL) AND
    (IDcurso     = 1 OR IDcurso     IS NULL) AND
    NOT(IDmodalidad IS NULL AND IDtipocurso IS NULL AND IDarea IS NULL AND IDcurso IS NULL)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, todas las respuestas me han sido muy útiles.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes reducir todo ese código a lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
    IDmodalidad,IDtipocurso,IDarea,IDcurso,tagbloque,contenido
FROM bloques 
WHERE 
    COALESCE(IDmodalidad, 1) = 1
    AND COALESCE(IDtipocurso, 1) = 1
    AND COALESCE(IDarea, 1) = 1
    AND COALESCE(IDcurso, 1) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero esto pueda servirte, dento de IN() tu puedes colocar ese valor especifico que indicas que no necesariamente sera igual para cada columna.

```
SELECT * FROM bloques
WHERE IDmodalidad IS NULL OR IDmodalidad IN (1)
OR IDtipocurso IS NULL OR IDmodalidad IN (1)
OR IDarea IS NULL OR IDmodalidad IN (1)
OR IDtipocurso IS NULL OR IDmodalidad IN (1)
```

Comment: ojo, esto con todos null devuelve registros y pasa a ser un sinsentido.